# Apache superset iFrame integration has CORS, not working

Tags: iframe, apache-superset

I want to integrate superset into an iframe.

1. I already added this into config.py

   `ENABLE_CORS = True`
2. Also in Config.py, I saw this:

   `HTTP_HEADERS: Dict[str, Any] = {}`

So no need to change

3. I copied admin role to Public role already
4. In iframe, I just used this url:
   [http://x.x.x.x:8088/superset/dashboard/world_health/?standalone=true"](http://x.x.x.x:8088/superset/dashboard/world_health/?standalone=true%22) width=800 height=800
5. when loading, I saw this:

   ```
   Request URL: http://x.x.x.x:8088/api/v1/chart/data?form_data=%7B%22slice_id%22%3A1133%7D&dashboard_id=1
   Request Method: POST
   Status Code: 400 BAD REQUEST
   Remote Address: 35.163.155.64:8088
   Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
   ```

The strange thing is I saw other API is working fine, such as this:
`http://x.x.x.x:8088/api/v1/chart/1133`

So any special issue for this API? `api/v1/chart/data?form_data`

I already copied all the permissions from admin to Public.